# AdMob Interstitial ad not showing on all my test devices

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

Hello I have implemented interstitial ads in my android game, first of all while testing the ads I've noticed that they appear only once per game session,I'd like to know if it will behave this way when I update the game because I don't want people to be overwhelmed by ads, once per game is sufficient.Second, when I test the ad on my S3 Mini it works correctly,however when I test it on a Galaxy S plus is does not work. The ad works like this,when the game is over I change set the value of a static variable called showAd inside my settings class to true.Then in my activity class I have:

```
  @Override
public void onUserInteraction(){
    if (Settings.showAd){
            displayInterstitial();
    }
}
```

so that when the user presses the screen after the game is over an ad pops up. Is the onUserInteraction method unavailable on lower android versions ?Thank you! ( I have added the S plus as a test device in the AdRequest method, still doesn't work)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you aren't still stuck on this, but in case anyone else ends up here:

1. "Will Interstitial Ads appear only once per game session?"

   - No, AdMob is not limiting itself to one Interstitial per game session. You need to handle that yourself. You could have displayInterstitial() set a flag so that the call to interstitial.show() only gets called once.
2. "Why don't test ads display on (insert reasonably old device here)?"

   - Testing AdMob ads on older devices is a bit of a crapshoot in my experience, especially if the device is running android 2.3 or lower (or has been cyanogen modded past this). Many of these devices pass bogus identifiers that can't be used with test modes. onUserInteraction() has been around since ye olde days of Android 1.5 so that shouldn't be a problem.
   - Also, depending on where you live, AdMob fill rates vary substantially. Because I live in Canada, I have had to run US proxies to see ANY ads from some networks through AdMob.

Comment: Man your comment is very useful.I have solved it, and I forgot to update the thread, my bad. Anyway it was a real dumb problem, I got used to having internet always on at all times on my cellphone so when I switched I didn't checked if it was on. Really dumb, but seriously thanks for answering I didn't knew some of things you said.